# Is it legal to use a quote or endorsement from a similar product

Tags: software

I stumbled across a video game description https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/gears-of-war-ultimate-edition-for-windows-10/9nblggh3shm5 where they quoted "The Verge" with the following:

> ...the best way to play Gears of War yet.” – The Verge

Their review is here: http://www.theverge.com/2015/8/24/9197081/gears-of-war-ultimate-edition-review-xbox-one where they reviewed the XBox One version of the game.

Is it legal to use such an endorsement for a product given that they aren't actually the same product? Given that cross-platform games will perform differently and sometimes even have different graphical enhancements, DLC, framerates, resolutions, etc. It seems misleading to me.

Just to clarify: I'm not singling out Microsoft here intentionally, I just happened to only see one quote in the Microsoft Store and it seemed odd. I believe many other companies do this when posting the review scores of a game, but they don't clarify that the scores are reflective of a score on another platform; which I believe does matter.

Comment: MS doesn't write descriptions do they? I though the devs did that

Comment: They are the publisher for the game, or rather "Microsoft Studios" is. I couldn't say with any amount of certainty that either the developer or publisher wrote that. Also, if Microsoft didn't write that then that's fine. If it was "The Coalition" (developer) then I still have the same question as before. It was never about Microsoft directly, I just felt this was a good example that I stumbled across. Thanks for replying.

Comment: ok. Makes sense.